# Android GridView crops items and doesn't properly update them

Tags: android, gridview

I'm having some trouble with my GridView. First of all it crops the last row(s) if the items are too heigh.
Funny thing is that I calculate their height in the `getView()` of the custom adapter I use. I just want the GridView to display 5 rows whose height depends on its height. Printing the parent height and the dayHeight to the console gives correct values.

**Adapter class:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View day = convertView;

        if (day == null) {     
            day = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day_gridcell, parent, false);    
        }

        int dayHeight = parent.getHeight() / 5; // month can spread over at most 5 weeks

        TextView tvDay = (TextView) day.findViewById(R.id.calendar_grid_cell);
        tvDay.setHeight(dayHeight);

        // set text and background colour of tvDay depending on position
}
```

**XML Layout for the fragment that contains the GridView**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<

TextView />

<LineaLayout /> <!-- horizontal layout with 7 children -->

 <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:id="@+id/calendar_grid"
            android:numColumns="7"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Furthermore I have the problem that depending on the position I set a certain text colour for the grid cell.

So let's say I want all elements with `position < X1` shall have blue text, the others red. When I generate a new data set (done in a public member function in which then `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called) and `X2 < X1`, then all items with `position < X1` have blue text even though some of them should have red text (namely the ones with position `X1 - X2`). The background colour however is set correctly. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I found out that the cropping was caused by `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`. I set up the project with AndroidStudio and it created the activity_main.xml with said layout. Changing it to LinearLayout fixed the cropping issue.
However, the second problem remains.

Comment: The whole point of GridView is that it will scroll your items if they happen to render more than can fit on the display.  If you don't want scrolling and instead just want a two dimensional set of views, why don't you use a GridLayout instead?

Comment: @DougStevenson Cause GridView has an OnItem(Long)ClickListener which, afaik, GridLayout hasn't? And I thought that the GridView is more efficient since it reuses the layouts? Might not be a big deal since I only display 32 items but still. Apart from that, my GridView doesn't even scroll untill I see the last row completely. It just cuts the last items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed/worked around it:

As stated already in the question, the `CoordinatorLayout` caused the cropping and changing it to another layout fixed that.

For the text colour problem: 
I just set the colour to let's say active colour before I determine which index actually gets which colour.